Error while running angular in Cypress: '@angular/compiler' is not available
During Cypress E2E testing, Angular is not running within. Getting following Angular error (we did migrate recently to version 18),
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> The injectable 'PlatformNavigation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

The injectable is part of a library that has been partially compiled.
However, the Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation is used as fallback.

Ideally, the library is processed using the Angular Linker to become fully AOT compiled.
Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3489:1


>message += `Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',\n`;
>message += `or manually provide the compiler with 'import >"@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.`;
>throw new Error(message);
 ^
>}
>else {
>  throw new Error('JIT compiler unavailable');


at getCompilerFacade (webpack://recorder/./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3489)
    at Module.ɵɵngDeclareFactory (webpack://recorder/./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:37979)
    at <static_initializer> (webpack://recorder/./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:33:46)
    at ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs (webpack://recorder/./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack://recorder/webpack/bootstrap:19)
    at ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/http.mjs (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\e2e\login\login.cy.js:7530:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack://recorder/webpack/bootstrap:19)
    at ./node_modules/keycloak-angular/fesm2022/keycloak-angular.mjs (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\e2e\login\login.cy.js:52812:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack://recorder/webpack/bootstrap:19)
    at eval (webpack://recorder/./cypress/e2e/login/login.cy.js:2)
From previous event:
    at Promise.longStackTracesCaptureStackTrace [as _captureStackTrace] (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:3486:19)
    at Promise._then (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:1239:17)
    at Promise.then (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:1132:17)
    at runScriptsFromUrls (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:111747:136)
    at Object.runScripts (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:111788:12)
    at $Cypress.onSpecWindow (http://localhost:52444/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:41303:67)



Can you actually successfully run the app via ng serve in a browser? Seems the error is not Cypress related, but Angular related, the app is somehow broken.

Yes, the app is working fine. It has many linked services

I have tried, aot: true, adding @angular/compiler at top and in jest-setup.js file: import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
Nothing worked, seems like an migrating issue as we did migrate recently to 18!

not sure how i solved, major issue was I wasnt running the localhost which cypress needs and reverted several suggestions I got from SO! thx

I am 99.999% sure that it is the angular JIT mode issue. Look at these two links and try it:
Angular 14: The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available
Migration from Node 14 to Node 18 - The injectable 'PlatformNavigation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler'
In AngularWebpackPlugin you should change:
    new AngularWebpackPlugin({
        mainPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
        tsConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json'),
        sourceMap: true,
        jitMode: '@angular/compiler' <-- replace jitMode: false/true with this
}),

Explanation:

"How to Enable JIT Compilation:
In your AngularWebpackPlugin configuration, you enable JIT mode by setting jitMode to '@angular/compiler':
JavaScript
new AngularWebpackPlugin({
   mainPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
   tsConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json'),
   sourceMap: true,
   jitMode: '@angular/compiler'
}),

This configuration tells Angular to use the JIT compiler provided by
the @angular/compiler package.
Purpose of JIT mode (@angular/compiler):
In this context, setting jitMode to @angular/compiler ensures that the Angular compiler is included to compile the templates dynamically at runtime rather than pre-compiling them during the build process."

Notice: Yes, explanation was provided by AI assistant. In documentation you won't find this explanation (at least I didn't).
Conclusion: The runtime error "The injectable 'PlatformNavigation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available." was the root cause for many other weird errors I was getting.
For everyone who are facing the similar type of error, try this solution first before you waste your time trying some workarounds or whatever (as I did)!
I also forgot to mention that in my angular.json, AOT flags are set to true which means that it will use JIT compiler only when it is needed in a runtime and the rest of the code will be compiled using AOT mode.
Please, let us know if that solved your problem. It solved mine and I hope it will solve yours.
Good luck!

Please edit your answer to include details of the solutions instead of just linking to them. That way if the pages you linked to are ever removed or modified, people who find your answer will still be able to get the information they need.
